# When I run the VBA code in Excel, I get the error User-defined type not defined. It hightlights my function to detect the last row with data in

Tags: sql, excel, vba

```
Private Sub uploadBtn_Click()
Option Explicit
Sub GenerateData()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim l_row As Long
    Dim s_employee_no As Integer
    Dim S_surname As String
    Dim s_forename As String
    Dim s_othernames As String
    Dim s_initials As String
    Dim s_DOB As Date
    Dim s_date_started As Date
    Dim s_date_left As Date
    Dim s_job_title As String
    Dim s_can_book_jobs As Boolean
    Dim s_notes As String
    Dim s_job_type As String
    Dim s_paxton_id As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    conn.Open "DSN=Backup;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=<database>"

    l_row = last_row_with_data(1, ActiveSheet) + 1

    s_employee_no = .Cells(l_row, 1)
    S_surname = .Cells(l_row, 2)
    s_forename = .Cells(l_row, 3)
    s_othernames .Cells(l_row, 4)
    s_initials = .Cells(l_row, 5)
    s_DOB = .Cells(l_row, 6)
    s_date_started = .Cells(l_row, 7)
    s_date_left = .Cells(l_row, 8)
    s_job_title = .Cells(l_row, 9)
    s_can_book_jobs = .Cells(l_row, 10)
    s_notes = .Cells(l_row, 11)
    s_job_type = .Cells(l_row, 12)
    s_paxton_id = .Cells(l_row, 13)

    conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_List (Employee_Number, Surname, Forename, Other_Names, Initials, DOB, Date_Started, Date_Left, Job_Title, Can_Book_In_Jobs, Notes, Job_Type, Paxton_ID) VALUES ('" & s_employee_no & "', '" & S_surname & "', '" & s_forename & "', '" & s_othernames & "', '" & s_initials & "', '" & s_DOB & "', '" & s_date_started & "', '" & s_date_left & "', '" & s_job_title & "', '" & s_can_book_in_jobs & "', '" & s_notes & "', '" & s_job_type & "', '" & s_paxton_id & "')"
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End With
End Sub

Public Function last_row_with_data(ByVal lng_column_number As Long, shCurrent As Varient) As Long
    last_row_with_data = shCurrent.Cells(Rows, Count, lng_column_number).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

The below piece of code is the part that's highlighted when the error occurs:

```
Public Function last_row_with_data(ByVal lng_column_number As Long, shCurrent As Varient) As Long
    last_row_with_data = shCurrent.Cells(Rows, Count, lng_column_number).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

As an insight into what i'm doing, I'm trying to upload information from the Excel file into a table that's already created in SQl, so if you have any tips to improve my work also, that would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Fixed the previous error thanks to BigBen, now I have a new one.
[This is the Error I Get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n2RD.png)
[This is the design of the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HceL.png)

Comment: Change `Rows, Count` to `Rows.Count`.

Comment: `Varient` is misspelled... should be `Variant`.

Comment: Thanks, BigBen, that fixed that. I now have new errors, I have uploaded the images in the edit. Cheers.

Comment: `Employee_Numer`.... from your second screenshot. That's 3 typos in your question :-)

Comment: If you have a new error you should ask a new question (after trying to fix it yourself).

Comment: Ahaha spotted that just after I posted (my predecessor created the database so I'm free of blame for that one). Thanks man.

Comment: I hope you don't have any Bobby Tables among your employees https://xkcd.com/327/